# Embedding Pygame to C++

Tags: c++, python, pygame

If embedding Pygame to C++ to have a game be an executable, is there any extra process I would have to use in order to use Pygame functions when embedding into C++? As opposed to just writing embedding code in C++ for normal Python code?

To clear cut the question I want to know if it's the same process without having to call different functions.

EDIT: My question is if I have to call different functions in C++ when embedding Python code that uses Pygame modules. I am NOT using pygame2exe nor py2exe. I never even mentioned those. My question is solely about code embedding.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking exactly. Are you wondering if you need to change Python function calls when using [Pygame2exe](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe)? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Oh god that circularity... Anyway, I highly doubt this has anything to do with game development. If you're looking for a way to compile Python code, @LaurentCouvidou has your answer.

Comment: Why are you trying to embed Python with Pygame into C++? Just use SDL, since that's what Pygame is built on. Pygame is supposed to be the boss of the application. You can write C++ modules that are loaded from Python, but if you try to embed Python and scripts that depend on Pygame, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: I would like to see this question reopened and an answer from @michael.bartnett giving some details about the pitfalls of such an approach.  If I wanted to use Python for 'scripting' inside of a game that's already mostly written in C++, would this not be the way to go?

Comment: @tugs I don't think I could add much more useful information than what's already out there: [0](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/421/how-do-you-add-a-scripting-language-to-a-game), [1](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17292/when-would-i-use-scripts-or-scripting-in-a-game-as-opposed-to-the-core-lang), [2](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5632/game-scripting-example-in-any-scripting-language), [3](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24889/scripting-language-with-class-instance-support)

Comment: More here: [4](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15955/simple-scripting-language-for-one-liner-type-scripts), [5](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/what-scripting-language-would-you-recommend-for-a-c-game-project), [6](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15444/game-engine-a-decent-way-architecture-wise-to-implement-scripting-support), [7](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/560/domain-specific-languages-for-scripting)

Comment: And last two: [8](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/33453/how-smartly-implement-scripting-in-game), [9](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/python-library-for-scripting-c-integration). You are embedding python, not pygame. Pygame is meant to be used as a library where the core of your game code, your window control, everything, is written in Python, with Pygame providing C-accelerated rendering and system event handling for input and such. This doesn't really warrant an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you embed Python into C++, you just have to set up the code to call the Python functions in C++. The Python libraries that you use, such as Pygame, have no effect on the C++ binding code you need to use.